# Implementation of library giving duplicate error

Tags: android, implementation

im trying to implement the 'com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:2.8.2' into my project and i am able to sync the gradle files but when i try to start the app it gives me this error

```
Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel found in modules core-1.5.0-

runtime (androidx.core:core:1.5.0) and support-compat-25.3.1-runtime (com.android.support:support-compat:25.3.1)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel$Stub found in modules core-1.5.0-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.5.0) and support-compat-25.3.1-runtime (com.android.support:support-compat:25.3.1)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel$Stub$Proxy found in modules core-1.5.0-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.5.0) and support-compat-25.3.1-runtime (com.android.support:support-compat:25.3.1)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.IResultReceiver found in modules core-1.5.0-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.5.0) and support-compat-25.3.1-runtime (com.android.support:support-compat:25.3.1)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.IResultReceiver$Stub found in modules core-1.5.0-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.5.0) and support-compat-25.3.1-runtime (com.android.support:support-compat:25.3.1)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.IResultReceiver$Stub$Proxy found in modules core-1.5.0-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.5.0) and support-compat-25.3.1-runtime (com.android.support:support-compat:25.3.1)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver found in modules core-1.5.0-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.5.0) and support-compat-25.3.1-runtime (com.android.support:support-compat:25.3.1)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver$1 found in modules core-1.5.0-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.5.0) and support-compat-25.3.1-runtime (com.android.support:support-compat:25.3.1)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver$MyResultReceiver found in modules core-1.5.0-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.5.0) and support-compat-25.3.1-runtime (com.android.support:support-compat:25.3.1)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver$MyRunnable found in modules core-1.5.0-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.5.0) and support-compat-25.3.1-runtime (com.android.support:support-compat:25.3.1)

Go to the documentation to learn how to Fix dependency resolution errors
```

i do not get why i will post my build.gradle below

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.jenson.resumeapp"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.5.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'

}
```

i do not seem to find anything on this that works?

Comment: Maybe it is a cache issue just try these 2 simple steps
1. Invalidate Cache & Restart then
2. Clean & Rebuild the project and try again.

Comment: Tried it doesnt work getting the same error

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add these lines in gradle.properties file

```
android.useAndroidX = true
android.enableJetifier = true
```

Comment: I just needed to add the android.enableJetifier = true but if you dont have the other one add that one to i would say. i already had the top one

Answer (score 0):

I was running into the same issue when I was implementing :

**com.github.shts:StoriesProgressView:3.0.0**

The problem, in my case at least, was that StoriesProgessView dependency was retrieving the same class from **com.android.support:support-compat** which is now already present in the androidx core package, causing the conflict to rise up.

This is how I went about it:
By checking out the Dependency tree, I found out that the StoriesProgressView was bringing in these dependencies, to remove those dependencies, I added the exlusion rule to the dependency like so:

```
implementation ('com.github.shts:StoriesProgressView:3.0.0') {
        exclude group: "com.android.support", module: "support-compat"
        exclude group: "com.android.support", module: "support-media-compat"
    }
```

this stopped pulling the classes from the old package.

In your case though, there doesn't seem to be any third-party dependency so probably following Malik Ali's answer should suffice. If it doesn't, give this one a go!

Answer (score 0):

Add this line in `gradle.properties`

```
android.enableJetifier = true
```